# How to compare two selects?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

[image]

```
  $email = a@a
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE email<>'$email' AND channel <> '( SELECT * FROM inscricoes WHERE email ='$email')' ORDER BY RAND();
```

How to get this result?

```
d@d    |    ddddd
```

Comment: Why `d@d` and not `c@c`?

Comment: Maybe `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email<>'$email' AND channel not in (SELECT channel FROM inscricoes WHERE email ='$email') ORDER BY RAND();`?

Comment: @chris85 not wot you code, I need to show to user, only the list of channels that he has not yet subscribed to. If he has already signed up he does not have to keep appearing for him the channels.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an anti-join pattern

```
SELECT u.email
     , u.channel 
  FROM users u

    -- anti-join, exclude rows with matching channel
  LEFT
  JOIN inscricoes i
    ON i.email = 'a@a' 
   AND i.channel = u.channel
 WHERE i.email IS NULL 

   AND u.email <> 'a@a'
 ORDER BY u.channel
```

That says, get all rows from `users` (except for the row for user = 'a@a')

And along with those rows, get any matching rows from `inscricoes`.

The twist is the condition in the `WHERE` clause.

We are guaranteed that any rows that had a match will have a non-NULL value for `i.channel` (since a NULL value would not satisfy the equality condition in the ON clause). So if we exclude rows that have a non-NULL value in `i.channel`, we are left with rows that didn't have a match.

---

An equivalent result can be obtained using a `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)` pattern

```
SELECT u.email
     , u.channel 
  FROM users u
 WHERE u.email <> 'a@a'
   AND NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1 
           FROM inscricoes i
          WHERE i.email = 'a@a' 
            AND i.channel = u.channel
       )
 ORDER BY u.channel
```

Comment: +1 for anti-join pattern. That might actually run faster than my subquery+filter solution if there are lots of rows

Comment: @stevendesu: in my experience, the anti-join pattern tends to be faster, at least with with large sets and with appropriate indexes available.  i wouldn't rule out other query patterns being faster in other cases (eg. no suitable indexes or nonsargable predicates, smaller sets, or sets with non-normative data distributions, statistics. it's good to have a variety of tools in our SQL toolbelts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure who taught you the `ORDER BY RAND()` trick, but I strongly advise forgetting it forever. Unless you **absolutely need** the results in a random order, this is just slowing down your queries for no reason.

That said, given the data you provided you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    users.email as email,
    users.channel as channel
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    inscricoes ON users.channel = inscricoes.channel
WHERE
    users.email <> '$email'
    AND
    inscricoes.email <> '$email'
```

This will create a temporary table:

```
+-------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+
| users.email | users.channel | inscricoes.email | inscricoes.channel |
+-------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+
| a@a         | aaaaa         | NULL             | NULL               |
| b@b         | bbbbb         | a@a              | bbbbb              |
| c@c         | ccccc         | a@a              | ccccc              |
| d@d         | ddddd         | NULL             | NULL               |
+-------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

Then it runs the query on this temporary table. However if you have multiple values in the `inscricoes` table for a single channel, this could lead to duplicate results. If that's the case, let us know and I'll work on a better query for you.

### Edit

Based on your comment, I think I have a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish. Give this query a try:

```
SELECT
    distinct(channel)
FROM
    users
WHERE
    email <> '$email'
    AND
    channel NOT IN (
        SELECT channel FROM inscricoes WHERE email = '$email'
    )
```

This will:

1. Get a list of channels that `a@a` is subscribed to (the subquery)
2. Get a list of all channels excluding `a@a`'s channel
3. Filter the first list from the second list
4. Return all results (ignoring duplicates)

Comment: absolutely no need random, I need to show to user, only the list of channels that he has not yet subscribed to. If he has already signed up he does not have to keep appearing for him the channels.